# Slick slider same height images within nested flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, slick.js

I am new to using flexbox.  I have deployed slick slider within one of the elements of a flexbox grid.  I am using background images with bottom aligned gradient elements across the different elements of the grid. 
This is the code

```
  <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="homepage-grid-left-col">
                <div class="homepage-grid-left-row">
                    <div class="homepage-grid-left-slider">
                        <div class="slide1">
                            <div class="grid-title">
                                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor amet raclette venmo hexagon beard, green juice brunch ethical pinterest salvia</h2><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide2">
                            <div class="grid-title">
                                <h2>Selfies intelligentsia kale chips before they sold out XOXO put a bird on it craft</h2><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide3">
                            <div class="grid-title">
                                <h2>Flexitarian freegan mumblecore kale chips dreamcatcher live-edge, squid microdosing selfies. Beard af la croix shaman</h2><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="homepage-grid-right-col">
                <div class="homepage-grid-top-right">
                    <div class="grid-title">
                        <h2>Ugh tousled fam microdosing<br>
                        Try-hard affogato</h2><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">Find out more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="homepage-grid-bottom-right">
                    <div class="homepage-grid-bottom-right-inner">
                        <div class="grid-left"></div>
                        <div class="grid-right">
                            <div class="grid-title">
                                <h2>Pabst iPhone truffaut</h2><a class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="#">Find out more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
                            html, body {
                            margin: 0;
                            }
                            .homepage-top .wrapper {
                                position: relative;
                            }
                            .homepage-top .wrapper:after {
                                padding-top: 50%;
                                display: block;
                                content: ' ';
                            }
                            .homepage-top .flex-container {
                                position: absolute;
                                top: 0;
                                bottom: 0;
                                right: 0;
                                left: 0;
                                padding: 5px;
                                display: flex;
                                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                                flex-wrap: wrap;
                            }
                            .homepage-top .flex-container>div {
                                height: 100%;
                                display: flex;
                                flex-direction: column;
                            }
                            .homepage-top .flex-container>div>div {
                                margin: 5px;
                                display: flex;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-left-col {
                                width: 50.5%;
                            }
                            /*Slider styling */
                            .homepage-grid-left-col .homepage-grid-left-row {
                                width: 98.5%;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-left-slider {
                                height: 100%;
                                display: flex;
                                overflow: hidden;
                            }

                            .slick-slide .slide1 {
                                background-image: url("http://p-hold.com/585/540");
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center;
                                padding-top: 78.5%;
                            }
                            .slick-slide .slide2 {
                                background-image: url("http://p-hold.com/585/540");
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center;
                                padding-top: 72.5%;
                            }
                            .slick-slide .slide3 {
                                background-image: url("http://p-hold.com/585/540");
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center;
                                padding-top: 78.5%;
                            }
                            .slick-slide .grid-title h2 {
                                font-size: 1.5em;
                                color: #fff;
                                text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
                            }
                            .slick-slide .grid-title {
                                padding: 2% 3% 7% 3%;
                                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, transparent), color-stop(15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)));
                                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%) filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000', GradientType=0);
                            }
                            .slick-dots li button {
                                border: 3px solid #fff;
                                border-radius: 50%;
                            }
                            .slick-dots li button::before {
                                color: transparent;
                                background: transparent;
                            }
                            .slick-dots li button:focus::before {
                                opacity: 0;
                                color: transparent;
                                background: transparent;
                                border-radius: 50%;
                            }
                            .slick-dots li button:hover::before, .slick-dots li.slick-active button::before {
                                opacity: 1;
                                color: #fff;
                                background: #fff;
                                border-radius: 50%;
                            }
                            .slick-dots {
                                bottom: 55px;
                            }
                            .slick-prev, .slick-next {
                                color: #fff;
                            }
                            .slick-prev {
                                left: 10px;
                                z-index: 10;
                            }
                            .slick-next {
                                right: 10px;
                                z-index: 10;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-right-col {
                                width: 49.5%;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-right-col .homepage-grid-top-right {
                                height: 50%;
                                background: #ddd;
                                background-image: url("http://p-hold.com/585/265");
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-right-col .homepage-grid-bottom-right {
                                height: 50%;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-bottom-right-inner, .grid-right {
                                flex: 1;
                                display: flex;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-bottom-right-inner .grid-left {
                                width: 50%;
                                margin-right: 5px;
                                background-image: url("http://p-hold.com/280/270");
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-bottom-right-inner .grid-right {
                                width: 50%;
                                background: #ddd;
                                margin-left: 5px;
                                background-image: url("http://p-hold.com/280/270");
                                background-size: cover;
                                background-position: center;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-top-right .grid-title {
                                height: 45%;
                                width: 100%;
                                padding: 10px 20px;
                                display: inline-block;
                                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, transparent), color-stop(10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)));
                                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%) filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000', GradientType=0);
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-bottom-right .grid-right .grid-title {
                                height: 45%;
                                width: 100%;
                                padding: 10px 20px;
                                display: inline-block;
                                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, transparent), color-stop(5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)));
                                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
                                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%) filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000', GradientType=0);
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-top-right .grid-title, .homepage-grid-bottom-right .grid-right .grid-title {
                                align-self: flex-end;
                            }
                            .homepage-grid-left-col .grid-title h2, .homepage-grid-top-right .grid-title h2, .homepage-grid-bottom-right-inner .grid-right .grid-title h2 {
                                font-size: 1.5em;
                                color: #fff;
                                text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
                            }
                            @media (max-width: 1200px) {
                                .homepage-grid-top-right .grid-title {
                                    height: 55%;
                                }
                                .homepage-grid-bottom-right .grid-right .grid-title {
                                    height: 70%;
                                }
                            }
                            @media (max-width: 992px) {
                                .homepage-grid-left-col {
                                    width: 98.5%;
                                }
                                .homepage-grid-right-col {
                                    width: 100%;
                                }
                                .homepage-top .wrapper:after {
                                    padding-top: 100%;
                                    display: block;
                                    content: ' ';
                                    margin-bottom: 99%;
                                }
                                .homepage-grid-right-col .homepage-grid-top-right {
                                    height: 70%;
                                }
                                .homepage-grid-right-col .homepage-grid-bottom-right {
                                    height: 70%;
                                }
                                .homepage-grid-top-right .grid-title, .homepage-grid-bottom-right .grid-right .grid-title {
                                    height: 40%;
                                }
                            }
                            @media (max-width: 768px) {
                                .homepage-grid-top-right .grid-title, .homepage-grid-bottom-right .grid-right .grid-title {
                                    height: 95%;
                                }
                            }
```

I would like to achieve the same within the slider whilst keeping the background image element as fix width.
However I am finding the elements change size dependind on the length of the overlay.

The issue is replicated in the codepen below: first and second slide background height changes depending on the length of the overlay.

https://codepen.io/nivims/full/MQzBdE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons your slider items are different heights.

- You used padding-top to create a aspect-ratio height, but you set different percentages to the slider items, this should be equal for all.
- The slider content affects the divs height, to prevent this you should make it position absolute within the slider element.

I created this pen for you, this might help you understand:

https://codepen.io/joostm020/pen/WMYmZv

```css
html,body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain; /* Try cover for no ugly borders! */
}
.slide .slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#slide1 { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x300); }
#slide2 { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x200); }
#slide3 { background-image: url(http://placehold.it/740x1000); }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide1">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum!</h1>
      <p>Donec blandit ullamcorper libero non fermentum. Etiam tincidunt ligula vitae lacus mattis, quis luctus felis viverra. Donec blandit ullamcorper libero non fermentum. Etiam tincidunt ligula vitae lacus mattis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide2">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum!</h1>
      <p>Donec blandit ullamcorper libero non fermentum. Etiam tincidunt ligula vitae lacus mattis, quis luctus felis viverra.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide3">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum!</h1>
      <p>Donec blandit ullamcorper libero non fermentum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Different paddings where my error (have corrected).  As you can see this is is still hapenning when padding values where set to the same value. Your pen does not seem to be rendering correctly

Comment: I have now tried your solution. The image height issue is fixex However giving the slider container absolute margin causes the captions to overlap over each other (which I had encountered before when developing this layout) If you could possibly recommend a work around this I will accept this answer.  Updated pen here https://codepen.io/nivims/pen/MQZWjy

Comment: @nivims You forgot to add a `position: relative;` to the parent of the absolute element. I forked your pen with 1 edit, check the bottom of CSS. https://codepen.io/joostm020/pen/qxLaYz